# How and when is old-releases.ubuntu.com updated?

Tags: release-management, mirrors

The old-releases.ubuntu.com mirror hosts the repositories for EOL Ubuntu releases. The [main page](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/) currently lists up to 11.10 (or 12.04.3 if you count point upgrades), but the [dists page](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/) lists up to 13.04. Why the discrepancy? When will the main page be updated? When will the newest EOL release (13.10) be shifted here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay, so I was able to get an answer on this from some of the archive/release team members. (The nitty-gritty gory procedures they use are documented [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/EndOfLifeProcess), though, but this is the basic information, here on this answer.)

I also have the log(s) of me asking this - see [this page](https://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2014/08/24/%23ubuntu-release.html) containing the logged chat on #ubuntu-release where I asked this.

---

According to the individual on the team(s) I talked to ([cjwatson](https://launchpad.net/~cjwatson)), the process of moving EOL releases from the mirrors to old-releases is a *manual* process and they do it whenever they get to it.  There is no set time for when they move the data from the archives to the old-releases page, but they do eventually get around to it.  The page I linked to detailing the process does explicitly state that "old-releases is by its nature not very regularly maintained" (quoted from the Wiki), so they do not regularly move the information over regularly and there is no schedule for it.