# apt-get claims 16.04 LTS does not exist

Tags: 16.04, apt, 15.04

I am currently using Ubuntu 15.04 and wish to upgrade to 16.04 LTS. I try:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

But I get:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
```

How do I move forward? Is my install simply reporting the wrong version number - how can I find out?

I mean, it looks like I am still on 15.04

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
```

What next steps can I take?

**UPDATE**

I followed the directions in [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) which caused a lot of 404 errors. I then realised that vivid was not in http://old-releases.ubuntu.com and search replaced those urls back to http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ and, bingo, updates working as they should.

**TL;DR:** The sources list was clearly wrong. Fixed it.

Comment: I normally prefer stoicism and will bow to the collective wisdom of the community. This one time, however, the community is wrong and the correct answer was basically edit /etc/apt/sources.list - the last update clearly got something wrong in there. Vivid is not currently in old releases and so that answer does not (yet) apply.

Answer (score 5):

There is no route to easily upgrade from 15.04 directly to 16.04. You would have to first upgrade to 15.10 and then upgrade to 16.04. In theory you could do this, see [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) , however, doing so is going to take longer and be more error prone than a fresh install.

IMO you are best off BACKING UP YOU DATA and performing a fresh install. As long as you DO NOT FORMAT your drive as part of the install, your data in $HOME should be preserved. If not you would need to restore from backup.

See [How to reinstall ubuntu and preserve home directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/662603/how-to-reinstall-ubuntu-and-preserve-home-directory) and [Re-install Ubuntu without losing data in home folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269880/re-install-ubuntu-without-losing-data-in-home-folder)

Comment: This is interesting but Vivid is still in http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu not old releases.

Comment: @MatthewBrownakaLordMatt https://askubuntu.com/a/515607/158442 - the migration to old-releases is not a regular process